# Where do you set the defaults settings for VS2017?

Tags: visual-studio-2017

When I installed the latest WDK it added a new option for `Spectre Mitigation` which cause linking to fail.  Instead of changing hundreds of projects, where I can simple change the default to disabled instead of enabled?

TIA!!

Answer (score 0):

Remove the Spectre Reference in the various:

`C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\Common7\IDE\VC\VCTargets\Platforms\($Platform)\ImportBefore\Default\Microsoft.Cpp.WDK.props`

files.